# Wordpress wp_get_attachment_image_src Size attribute

Tags: php, wordpress, image, post

i am calling in a function to show the post featured image and post it a background image. The dimensions are set within the div yet my client updates originals that are huge and wondering if theres a way to set the size of the image to scale them down:

```
<?php

    $catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=23&posts_per_page=1' );

    while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();

    $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'featured' );?>

<div onclick="window.location='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">

    <div class="front-page-featured-post"  style="background: url(<?php echo $src[0]; ?> ); background-size: cover; background-repeat:no-repeat;">
```

in my functions:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
  add_image_size('featured', 370, 240, true);
```

Comment: Please take a look at this tutorial on [how to create additional image sizes in WP](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-additional-image-sizes-in-wordpress/). It teaches how to create image sizes, choose between hard and soft crop and how to fetch the correct size image in the theme.

Comment: So I have followed the tutorial but the images are still far too big.

Comment: Have you re-generated the thumbnails? Keep in mind that once you added `add_image_size` only the newly uploaded images will have this _new size_. For all older previously uploaded images you'll need to re-generate thumbnails, a step that is also covered in that tutorial.

Comment: I have indeed re-generated the thumbs but still showing as the original size.

Comment: Regenerate thumbnails should do it.If there's a wider problem that your client uploads images that are much too big, you can also use a plugin like imsanity to limit the maximum size.

Comment: What does `print_r($src)` shows? (add it after the line `$src = wp_get_attachment_image_src(...`)

Comment: Array ( [0] => http:/... [1] => 320 [2] => 240 [3] => )

Comment: This is what the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src#Return_Value) says about the Return Values of `wp_get_attachment_image()`: "[3] => boolean: true if $url is a resized image, false if it is the original.". In your case, `[3] => false` (empty = false), so the image was not resized. Maybe because it's 320px wide, when "featured" image size is 370px? If the image file is still too large, check JPEG compression, maybe it's at best quality leading to a larger file.

Comment: So what would be the best for me to do in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
set_post_thumbnail_size( 370, 340 );
```

Comment: I have indeed - this didn't work, maybe something is missing from theme support?

Comment: How about sending the size when you retrieve it: 
`wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_id, array( 370, 240 ), true )`

Comment: I am losing the image now, although it showing to be true [2] - It shows the default Wordpress image icon and not the image...

Comment: That should be 
`wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), array( 370, 240 ), true )`
Sorry, I wasn't clear.

Comment: That's probably because the images are still original size. The different sizes get generated when a new image is uploaded. Try uploading a new image and testing after that. By now you set both the default Featured image size through `set_post_thumbnail_size( 370, 340 )`; and registered an additional sizing as `add_image_size('featured', 370, 240, true);`. Hope it helps!

Comment: Also, have a look at [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) for regenerating images after changing the sizes. I'm not into adding a plug-in for everything but it's worth a check.

Comment: The images are for sure the originals, they are just not regenerating for some reason.

Comment: The plugin should allow you to do that from withing the Dashboard.

Answer (score -1):

You need to regenerate the images after you implement the new thumbnail size, just use this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/
to regenerate all the images and it will create new images with dimensions 370x240

Comment: That is the issue, that is failing on me.

Comment: Do you receive any error when you use Tools -> Regen. Thumbnails menu?

Comment: None at all it says it has regenerated them

Comment: Where are add_theme_support and add_image_size....in some function or outside a function in functions.php, check if they are called. Additional you can try to load them after theme setup like this:
`function wpse_setup_theme() {
   add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
   add_image_size('featured', 370, 240, true);
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpse_setup_theme' );`

Comment: add_theme and add_image_size are in the functions.php file

Comment: It would also appear that when you go into the media library, edit the image the image icon is failing to load.